# Should I specify JWT audience and issuer if I have only one SPA client?

Tags: jwt, .net, asp.net

I have an API server (ASP.NET Core 5) and SPA client (ASP.NET Blazor). Nothing else: no external oauth servers, identity providers and whatnot

To secure access, the server issues and validates access tokens (JWTs) and refresh tokens.

A JWT typically has "audience" and "issuer" claims. Every tutorial and reference implementation seems to specify them, even for a simple use case like mine.

In my use case I assume the server is both issuer and audience. Is there any benefit to include these claims in my JWTs?

Comment: Which rfc? Are you using OIDC or plain OAuth2.0? Or are you using plain JWT rfc7519? If so read sections 11 and 12 and in your question explain what context you have so someone might be able to give an appropriate answer

Comment: I'm generating and validating JWTs manually, as stated. I'm not using any of that stuff. Forget about the RFC for a moment. When using JWTs like that, without an identity provider, is there a benefit to audience and issuer? The tooling I'm using (aspnet core) works even when I don't include those claims. Should I include them?

Comment: If you ask that we ignore the rfc, what would you suggest someone base the answer on? You seem to be fishing for anyone to say you don't need them which is an insincere question

Comment: I've removed mention of the RFC. The question is the same. All articles and tutorials blindly copy each other without explaining why those claims are needed in a simple case like this, where the API server is responsible for auth. Are they needed?

Comment: Not necessarily, since issuer and audience are not only the same instance here (namely the web API) but there is also no ambiguity within your environment as there is only one issuer/audience (you might look into JWK as you don't need to manage a public key in such a scenario). The samples you are referring to are generally assuming scenarios where there's a some sort of many-to-many relationship between audiences and issuers as it is common among federated identity with 3rd party providers. It does make since to assign the token to your API though and not rely solely on your encryption.

Comment: Disclaimer: I only refer to Ionix's question as is. My intention is not to encourage anyone to just act over the RFC's head and roll one's own security, nor to rely on the more often than not low quality samples for self-contained OAuth/OIDC samples in the .NET ecosystem floating around the web.

Comment: @Beltway Thank you. Though I don't understand this bit from your comment: *"...to assign the token to your API though and not rely solely on your encryption"*. What did you mean by assigning the token?

Comment: The issuer and audience claim 'assign' (admittedly poor phrasing) to the identity provider and resource server respectively. That means upon validation it can be ensured who (allegedly) signed the token and who is intended to receive it. Imagine a STS like Microsoft's serving thousands of audiences. Assuming it uses but on signing key (which it in truth does not) a token issued for `resource1` might be accepted for `resource2` since there would be no other way of telling the difference (at least in this simplified scenario).

Comment: @Beltway Understood, thanks. I suppose for my simple use case it's not necessary, but with a view to one day upgrading to a identity provider, it may make it easier if I use all the standard claims in my tokens...

Comment: Setting and validating audiences and issuers with ASP.NET Core is next to a no-brainer so there's no real reason against it.

Comment: @Beltway Agreed with the first part it's really easy. A reason against it is when one isn't actually using it, it just complicates maintenance ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer complements the comments on the original question.

**What do these claims mean anyway?**

[*Issuer*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.1):
The `iss`-claim corresponds to the authority who issued the token. In federated identity environments this grants information about

- who signed the token;
- and subsequently where the validating party should validate the signature;

For instance, the issuer claim of a token issued by Azure AD typically looks somewhat like this: `https://sts.windows.net/{TENANT}`.

In a scenario with multiple possible identity providers this information is crucial to tell them apart and determine towards where the resource owner has authenticated himself to access the resource.

[*Audience*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.3): The audience is the intended recipient of the token. This information is required to ensure a token issued to access `some-resource.com` is not accepted as valid when offered to `some-other-resource.com`.

**Do we need them in the specified scenario?**

In theory, yes; in practice, probably not. As long as tokens are signed and you possess exclusive knowledge about your signing key, including these claims offers little to no benefit (to reiterate: only as long you serve but a single audience).

**What would this look like in ASP.NET?**

When sticking to the libraries and extensions offered by Microsoft, configuring the setting and validation of these claims is a matter of just a few lines:

Setting the claims:

```
new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Issuer = "https://my-resource.com",
    Audience = "https://my-resource.com",
    /*...*/
};
```

Validating them:

```
new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = "https://my-resource.com",
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = "https://my-resource.com",
    /*...*/
};
```

Note that this checks for the string value only, for calling the token validation endpoints of third party providers further configuration of the authentication middleware is required.

**Comment on the mentioned tutorials**

> Every tutorial and reference implementation seems to specify them,
> even for a simple use case like mine.

I made this observation too and am rather surprised that these samples gain so much traction. A lot of them seem to forget the main point of asymmetric encryption of issued tokens is to circumvent the issue of storing and providing secrets amongst multiple partially untrusted parties, which is not the case in the given scenario. My advice: go for JWK and symmetrically encrypt your tokens, ideally on top of signing. Third parties won't have insight into the user specific claim you issue and can't make assumptions about your API from the intel given in your token (though your security naturally shouldn't rely on that).

Comment: @ChrisNevill Fixed it.